# Should I correct an imam who forces his opinions on his community?

Tags: salat, madhhab, imam-al-jamaah, behavior

Salam, my masjid has a new Imam who seems to be a very friendly and knowledgeable brother Masha Allah. But one thing he does is in Salah, he seems to force the congregation to follow his opinion on matters where the scholars have disagreed.

For example he says when the Salah has ended, everyone must wait till the Imam has finished both of his salams, before offering their salam. I know this is the majority opinion among the scholars, but many brothers who were taught the Hanafi method see this as contrary to what they learned since childhood. He also says that if one comes late to Jummah where they miss the second bowing (ruku) then they need to pray Zuhr Salah. Again this goes against the teachings of the Hanafi school.

I myself do not follow that school, but I think it might be unfair to the many brothers who do. Since these are matters where there is disagreement, I would prefer the Imam not mention it or make it a point to always remind the congregation of. We should be inclusive, and respectful of others' opinions even if we believe the opinion we follow is stronger.

What do you think I should do? Mention this to the Imam or not?

Comment: Usually "Should I" questions are advice-requests and hardly on-topic as they call for opinion-based answers. But I guess there's a middway solution for such cases.

Comment: I suggest that you separate your question into multiple questions: one for each topic.To say that the Hanafi school for taslim is al-muqarana (same time as the Imam) is not entirely accurate (see [Badā'i al-Sanā'i](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=12&ID=85&idfrom=316&idto=338&bookid=12&startno=22)).

Comment: @III-AK-III why split the question if it is basically whether he should or not argue or correct the Imam the problem is rather to judge whether this question has a definit answer or will anybody come with his opinion.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, it will be difficult to answer both concerns in one question. Basically, there is nothing to tell his imam if these are the only two concerns since the Hanafis are not absolutely united on them. Moreover, discussions on different schools of jurisprudence rarely become fruitful (we have the opposite situation in our masjid: the imam is a strong adherent of the Hanafi school, while a portion of the attendants are Hanbalis).