# What is the "established madhhab" for each of the 4 sunni schools of fiqh?

Tags: hanafi, madhhab, shafii, maliki, hanbali

Basically the question [Should I correct an imam who forces his opinions on his community?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37600/should-i-correct-an-imam-who-forces-his-opinions-on-his-community) is the reason for me to ask the above question.
As I know (or learnt) that even if abu Hanifa holds the opinion that in a congregation the people following the Imam can end the prayer at the same time with him or earlier, but Mohammad ibn al-Hassan a-Shaybani and abu Yusuf followed the opinion of the majority of scholars saying one must follow the Imam and only do the salam if he has finished it.

So I asked myself what is the established madhhab of the hanafi school and whom are the scholars whom made this final stablization.

BTW it would be nice to know the same for the maliki and hanbali (and if possible also the dhahiri/zahiri) school as i assume that i've covered the shafi'i school already in my answer on [Levels of obligatoriness of rulings within schools of law](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36246/levels-of-obligatoriness-of-rulings-within-schools-of-law)

Comment: This is not the first instance where hanafis don't follow their Madhab/imam. Other instances praying fajr jamaat early in ramadaan and late outside ramadaan. Abu hanafi advocated late fajr jamaat throughout the year.Hanafis Spontaneously answering prophet is best of creation, abu hanifa staying silent on same question, abu hanifa intensely disliked someone making dua by means of creation, hanafis make dua by waseelah of creation.

Comment: What do you mean by "established madhhab"?

Comment: @Crimson see the linked post (at the end of my post) my answer shows what is meant.